# Which URL should I use when adding a Git submodule?

Tags: git, url, github, git-submodules, git-clone

[Github: Which URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) recommends [cloning with HTTPS](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-recommended).

But, I see that [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) uses [`git://` in `.gitsubmoudle`](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/commit/85b67d7f3d6aa134be942aa1099b0938a6d36060).

Which is best for an open-source project that I want others to be able to easily clone recursively?

Answer (score 1):

If you've other contributors, `https` would be my suggestion, since the proxy servers (and ISPs) do not block those requests, in general.

OTOH, if you can be sure (or make sure), that they would not be using any such ISP services, you can choose to provide them access via any of those methods. I personally prefer SSH over other protocols.